# Javascript button.onclick not functioning like I thought

Tags: javascript, button, onclick, eventhandler

So I was in the presumption that this function

```
button.onclick = exampleFunk;
```

would give me a handler on each button when I click them, but it doesn't. When replacing it with:

```
button.onclick = alert("bananas");
```

I'm getting alerts at page onload. The problem is already solved with this:

```
    button.setAttribute("onclick", "removeIssue(this)");
```

Out of curiousity... **What's going on?**

*edited layout of post*

**EDIT**

```
var issues = [];

window.onload = function () {
    //alert("venster geladen");
    issuesToList()
}



function issuesToList(data) {
    /*alert( 
        "array length is " + data.issues.length + "\n" +
        "total_count is " + data.total_count + "\n" +
        "limit is " + data.limit + "\n" + 
        "offset is " + data.offset + "\n" + ""
        );*/

    for (i = 0; i < data.issues.length; i++) {
        issue = data.issues[i];
        createIssue(issue);
    }
}


function createIssue(issue){


    var id = issue.id;
    var tracker = issue.tracker;
    var status = issue.status;
    var priority = issue.priority;
    var subject = issue.subject;
    var description = issue.description;
    var assignee = issue.assignee;
    var watchers = issue.watchers;

    var ticket = new Issue(id, tracker, status, priority, subject, description, assignee, watchers);
    issues.push(ticket);

    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.innerHTML = "-";


    button.onclick = function (){ alert("bananas")};
    //button.setAttribute("onclick", "removeIssue(this)");

    var item = document.createElement("div");       
    item.setAttribute("id", id);
    item.appendChild(button);
    item.innerHTML += " " + subject;

    var container = document.getElementById("container");
    container.appendChild(item);


}


function removeIssue(e){
    var key = e.parentNode.getAttribute("id");
    var count = issues.length;

    if(confirm("Confirm to delete")){
        for(i=0; i<count; i++){
                if (issues[i].id == key ){
                issues.splice(i,1);
                var element = document.getElementById(key);
                element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
            }
        }
    }
}


function Issue(id, tracker, status, priority, subject, description, assignee, watchers){
    this.id = id;
    this.tracker = tracker;
    this.status = status;
    this.priority = priority;
    this.subject = subject;
    this.description = description;
    this.assignee = assignee;
    this.watchers = watchers;
}
```

**EDIT**

```
<body>

    <h1>List of Issues</h1>
    <div id="container"></div>

    <script src="http://www.redmine.org/issues.json?limit=10&callback=issuesToList"></script>


</body>
```

Comment: can you try this button.addEventListener("click", function() { alert("alert");}); ?

Comment: button.addEventListener("click", alert("alert"));      I tried this. because yours @sushil also didn't  work. Getting the alerts on page load again

Comment: try calling it in the onload() function

Comment: Your code needed you to add text nodes instead of modifying the `innerHTML` of a parent object. See my answer with the updated information and a working example.

Answer (score 3):

You need to mask the `alert` in a `function`:

```
button.onclick = function (){ alert("bananas")};
```

As such:

```js
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
var t = document.createTextNode("CLICK ME");
btn.appendChild(t); 
btn.onclick = function() {alert("bananas")};
document.body.appendChild(btn);
```

Comment: when adding it to mine it doesn't work, ill give the full code

Answer (score 0):

You can bind arguments to the function so that it returns with the function you want it to call using your arguments (with additional arguments passed later added on to the end). This way doesn't require writing extraneous code (when all you want to do is call a single function) and looks a lot sleeker. See the following example:

```
button.onclick = alert.bind(window, "bananas");
```

An unrelated example of how it works in your own code is like this:

```
var alert2 = alert.bind(window, 'Predefined arg');
alert2(); // 'Predefined arg'
alert2('Unused'); // 'Predefined arg'
```

For IE, this requires IE9 as a minimum. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) for more information.

---

**EDIT:** I've looked closer at your code and there was one significant change that was needed for it to work... You cannot add onto the `innerHTML` when you've added JavaScript properties to a child element. Changing the `innerHTML` of the parent element will convert your element into HTML, which won't have the `onclick` property you made before. Use `element.appendChild(document.createTextNode('My text'))` to add text dynamically.

See a functioning example here: http://jsfiddle.net/2ftmh0gh/2/

Comment: So how do I attach it to the removeIssue() function. removeIssue.bind() does not work.

Comment: You'd want to use `removeIssue.bind(window, item)`. The first argument is what you want `this` to be for that function (if you don't need it, just use `window` all the time) and the second argument is the first argument the function will read. It uses variables that you have access to when that line is first called, not later when you click the button.

Comment: To use variables the click event passes to the function, you'd just use `button.setAttribute("onclick", removeIssue);` and `this` in `removeIssue` would be the button element while `e`/the first argument would be the click event data.

Answer (score 0):

> Whats going on?

You `alert()` is executed on page load because its a `function call`. When the execution of your script reaches that line your assignment

```
button.onclick = alert("bananas");
```

is actually executing the alert statement and not assigning it to `button.onclick`

Comment: Without calling the function no buttons... so the statement shouldn't be used here?

Comment: To assign it, wrap it inside a `function` so it gets executed only on `click`